# How to check if javascript finishes loading in pyqt5?

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt5

I wrote a program in `pyqt5`.

The page is rendered with javascript.

As the javascript takes some time to execute, I want to make sure the page is fully loaded.

Currently, my program checks whether a value in the page changes.

However, the IDLE restarts.

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Any other better approach to check if javascript finishes?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Render(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.html = ""
        self.first_pass = True
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        super(Render, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._load_finished)
        self.loadProgress.connect(print)
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _load_finished(self, result):
        if result:
            self.call_js()

    def call_js(self):
        self.runJavaScript('document.getElementById("txtDistance").value = "1";')
        self.runJavaScript("void(0)")
        self.runJavaScript("CheckUserWhere();")

######################## check value change #####################
        while True:
            self.toHtml(self.get_data)
            if BeautifulSoup(self.html, 'html.parser').find('div', {'id': 'MarketRules'}).find('span').text == '1':
                break
        self.toHtml(self.callable)

    def get_data(self, data):
        self.html = data
        print(self.html)

    def callable(self, data):
        self.html = data
        self.app.quit()

url = "https://land.3fang.com/LandAssessment/b6d8b2c8-bd4f-4bd4-9d22-ca49a7a2dc1f.html"
web = Render(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(web.html, 'html.parser')
_bpgj = soup.find('b', {'id':"_bpgj"}).string
_bSumPrice = soup.find('b', {'id':"_bSumPrice"}).string
print(_bpgj, _bSumPrice)
```

Error appeared:

```
0
22
70
js: A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://api.map.baidu.com/getscript?v=1.3&ak=&services=&t=20181212032835, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
js: A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://api.map.baidu.com/getscript?v=1.3&ak=&services=&t=20181212032835, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
js: Uncaught ReferenceError: SetTop is not defined
100
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use while True in Qt since it locks the eventLoop, instead you should do the check with runJavaScript and use a QEventLoop to wait.

```
from functools import partial

# ...

class Render(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    # ...

    def call_js(self):
        self.runJavaScript('document.getElementById("txtDistance").value = "1";')
        self.runJavaScript("void(0)")
        self.runJavaScript("CheckUserWhere();")
        self.wait()
        self.toHtml(self.callable)

    def wait(self):
        loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
        _script = '''
            function task(){
                var element = document.getElementById("MarketRules");
                if (element == null)
                    return false;
                var tags = element.getElementsByTagName("span");
                for(i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
                    if (tags[i].innerText == "1")
                        return true;
                return false;
            }
            task();
        '''
        def callback(result):
            if result:
                loop.quit()
            else:
                wrapper = partial(self.runJavaScript, _script, callback)
                QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(200, wrapper)
        self.runJavaScript(_script, callback)
        loop.exec_()

    # ...
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the program did not terminate.

Comment: @Chan Have you executed it in the CMD?

Comment: Still the same situation

Comment: @Chan Have you tried another machine? Have you tried another network? do not use IDLE

Comment: I tried to use microsoft visual studio but the same happened.

Comment: @Chan Have you tried in the CMD? Have you tried in another network and in another computer to discard that your computer is the cause of the error?

Comment: I tried the code in another computer with visual studio and I obtained the error message shown at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @Chan That's not a mistake, it's a warning and I get it too, but I also get the numbers

Comment: Thank you, eyllanesc. However, I don't know why the program keeps running.